# Renamed issues in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm working on programming with Swift for the first time, and in doing so I'm following along with [this](http://codewithchris.com/iphone-app-connect-to-mysql-database/) tutorial. Unfortunately it looks like the tutorial is a little outdated and most of the code is throwing Buildtime errors. The most reoccurring error is the `NSURLSession has been renamed to URLSession`. I've tried letting Swift fix it, but in many cases it just starts throwing warnings.I'm also getting a `Value type HomeModel has no member'parseJSON'` error as well as a `NSDat is not implicitly convertible to data` error. From what I can tell, it looks like the NSURL is no longer used, but I'm not sure about the other two. Seeing how this is the first Swift project I've worked on, I'm not sure how to fix these. Can someone provide some insight on how to fix these mistakes?

here is the code:

```
import Foundation

protocol HomeModelProtocal: class {
    func itemsDownloaded(items: NSArray)
}


class HomeModel: NSObject, NSURLSessionDataDelegate {

    //properties

    weak var delegate: HomeModelProtocal!

    var data : NSMutableData = NSMutableData()

    let urlPath: String = "http://testurl.com/service.php" //this will be changed to the path where service.php lives


    func downloadItems() {

        let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
        var session: NSURLSession!
        let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()


        session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url)

        task.resume()

    }

    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveData data: NSData) {
        self.data.appendData(data);

    }

    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: NSError?) {
        if error != nil {
            print("Failed to download data")
        }else {
            print("Data downloaded")
            self.parseJSON()
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several basic types have dropped the "NS" prefix in Swift 3.0. Earlier in swift 2.2, we used to have `NSUserDefaults`, `NSURLSession`, `NSFileManager` etc. Now, most of them dropped their prefix "NS" and changed to `UserDefaults`, `URLSession`, `FileManager` etc.

Your code contains a lot of types with 'NS' prefix. By simply removing it, your code can be converted to Swift 3. Your converted code looks like as shown below:

```
protocol HomeModelProtocal: class {
   func itemsDownloaded(items: NSArray)
}

class HomeModel: NSObject, URLSessionDataDelegate {

   //properties

   weak var delegate: HomeModelProtocal!

   var data : Data = Data()

   let urlPath: String = "http://testurl.com/service.php" //this will be changed to the path where service.php lives


   func downloadItems() {

      let url: URL = URL(string: urlPath)!
      var session: URLSession!
      let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default

      session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

      let task = session.dataTask(with: url)

      task.resume()
   }

   func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {
       self.data.append(data);
   }

   func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
       if error != nil {
          print("Failed to download data")
       }else {
          print("Data downloaded")
          self.parseJSON() // This class doesn't have a function parseJSON(). So, it's giving you an error like this
       }
   }
}
```

Also, I don't see any function called `parseJSON()` in your class. I believe you have to add it.